# How to setup local server on Linux for testing Dokku?

Tags: linux, nginx, dokku

I'm new to **Dokku** and **nginx** server and I'm trying to set up server locally on **Linux Ubuntu 20.04** for testing purpose instead of using one such as **Hetzner (Cloud)** or DigitalOcean (which already contains [Dokku image](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/dokku) which is older version of Dokku than the one I need) which could cause unwanted financial expenses.

More precisely is I'm trying to setup domain address in my `/etc/hosts` file, e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

188.x.xx.xxx    domain.com
```

By following this [Dokku setup tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-your-on-heroku-with-dokku/) and passed it one of following commands:

```
$ dokku domains:set-global localhost
$ dokku domains:set-global domain.com
```

But once I execute following command (in order to show created `djangotutorial` app):

```
$ dokku config:show djangotutorial
```

... I get this as output:

```
=====> djangotutorial env vars
NO_VHOST:  1
```

From there everything I execute normally in mentioned tutorial until I execute following command (to push to remote server):

```
$ git push dokku main
```

... I get following message:

> ssh: connect to host domain.com port 22: Connection timed out fatal:
> Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Is there a way to achieve this and how by mentioned info?

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.